# The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:?

Tags: python, exception, key, data-analysis, keyerror

I am working on a dataset that has a column of Airbags, type: pandas.core.series.Series.

Airbags Column:

[image: Airbags Column]

I want to find the number of airbags rather than their position, so I ran the following code:

```
type(data['Airbags'])
data['Airbags'] = data['Airbags'].replace(np.nan, '0')
len(data['Airbags'][1].split(','))     #gives correct output
```

But when I ran a loop to do this for the entire column:

```
 for i in range(1198):
  if(data['Airbags'][i]=='0'):
   data['Airbags_count'][i]=0
  else:
   data['Airbags_count'][i]=len(data['Airbags'][i].split(','))
```

---

I get this error: KeyError: 252

[image: ERROR]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:
```

My goal is to get the count of the airbags. If anyone has another approach or a solution to this problem, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
data['airbags'].str.count('airbag').sum()
```

But first I'd probably want to know what is in all rows:

```
data['airbags'].value_counts()
```